# Find inside a seq of Tuple

Tags: f#

I have seq of Tuple of type `(x: int, y:bool)` and I want to find the min `x` of the items who has `y=isMin`  in `valList` if `isMin` is true.

```
let valList = seq{ for i =0 to 8 do yield (GetVal (i,not isMin),not isMin) } 
let onlyMinType (x: int, y:bool) = if y==isMin then x
let maxVal = valList |> Seq.collect(onlyMinType) |> if isMin then Seq.min else Seq.max
maxVal
```

I dont know what to do here
`Seq.collect(onlyMinType)` and function `onlyMinType`

Comment: This is a good problem for practicing common sequence operators. For instance, try to solve the problem by using `Seq.filter` to get the subset of the list where the `isMin` flag is true and then think about how you can sort the sequence and extract the first component.

Comment: Could you either remove or define `GetVal`?  Also, it looks like your algorithm does something more than simply finding the min value (`let maxVal`).  Could you either explain what you want for that or take it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Seq.minBy` in a couple of different ways:

```
[(1, false); (2, true); (0, true); (-1, false)]
|> Seq.filter snd
|> Seq.minBy fst
|> fst
```

or

```
[(1, false); (2, true); (0, true); (-1, false)]
|> Seq.minBy (fun (n, b) -> if b then n else Int32.MaxValue)
|> fst
```

would work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

> I have `seq` of `Tuple`s of type `(x: int, y:bool)` and I want to find the min `x` of the items who has `y=isMin` in `valList if`isMin`is`true`.

The idea is to use [`Seq.filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340367.aspx) [`snd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340353.aspx) to filter values from seq which second value is `true`. Then use [`Seq.sortBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353610.aspx) [`fst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx) to sort seq basing on the first value of each tuple.

```
> (Seq.sortBy fst << Seq.filter snd) [(1, false); (2, true); (0, true)];;
val it : seq<int * bool> = seq [(0, true); (2, true)]
```